# "es waren dies eine Taschenbibel, ..."

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronoun

The question is on *dies* as highlighted in this sentence from *Amerika* (*Der Verschollene*) by Franz Kafka.

> Beim Hervorsuchen einiger Gegenstände, die zuunterst lagen – es waren **dies** eine Taschenbibel, Briefpapier und die Photographien der Eltern –, fiel ihm die Mütze vom Kopf und in den Koffer.

**QUESTION**

1. Which part of speech (e.g. pronoun, adverb) is *dies*?
2. What does it mean in the context of the sentence?

**BACKGROUND**

I know that *dies* could be a determiner of a noun to follow or a (self-standing) pronoun referring to a neuter noun or some foregoing clause (fact, idea).

It seems clear that *dies* is not a determiner of *Taschenbibel*.

Could it be that *dies* is apposite to the list that follows, i.e. *eine Taschenbibel, Briefpapier und die Photographien der Eltern*?

If so the clause might be:

> there were **these things**, a pocket bible...

Comment: I don't know the grammar, but indeed "dies" refers to the "Gegenstände, die zuunterst lagen".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Dies* is a demonstrative pronoun that can be used in two ways:

1. adjective use: *Dies[es]* Haus ist grün*, like in "this house is green".
2. substantive use: Here the pronoun refers to something within the context: *Ich sah ein Haus. Dies[es] war grün*.

What you are seeing here is the substantive use - *Dies* refers to the *Gegenstände* in the previous sentence, so your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 3):

*dies* is a pronoun, or more precise: a demonstrate (*Demonstrativpronomen* in German).

In your example, it refers back to the (rather unspecific)  *Gegenstände* ('things'), which are then further specified by the following list (*eine Taschenbibel, Briefpapier und die Photographien der Eltern*).

Answer (score 0):

**Dies** is a demonstrative pronoun.

But why this complicated construction?

> Er kramte sein Zeug zusammen. **Es** waren zwei Bücher, ein Notizheft und Schreibzeug.

The list is given without special focus or ambition.

> Er kramte sein Zeug zusammen. **Dies** waren zwei Bücher, ein Notizheft und Schreibzeug.

Strong focus on *Zeug*.

> Er kramte sein Zeug zusammen. **Es** waren **dies** zwei Bücher, ein Notizheft und Schreibzeug.

Focus on the details.