# Using "dies" instead of the form of the pronoun that matches the gender and number of the referent

Tags: grammatical-case, pronoun

This post is on *dies* as used in these excerpts from chapter '[Weg nach Ramses](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/amerika-9768/13)' of *Amerika* (*Der Verschollene*) by Franz Kafka.

> Beim Hervorsuchen einiger **Gegenstände**, die zuunterst lagen – es waren **dies** eine Taschenbibel, Briefpapier und die Photographien der Eltern –, fiel ihm die Mütze vom Kopf und in den Koffer.
> Diese Gefahr ist also vorläufig abgewehrt‹, sagte sich Karl und kehrte zum Tisch zurück. Wenn ihre Schläfrigkeit nicht Vorwand war, war ja alles gut. Unangenehm war bloß, daß der eine Irländer war. Karl wußte nicht mehr genau, in welchem Buch er einmal zu Hause gelesen hatte, daß man sich in Amerika vor den Irländern hüten solle. Während seines Aufenthaltes beim Onkel hätte er freilich die beste **Gelegenheit** gehabt, der Frage nach der Gefährlichkeit der Irländer auf den Grund zu gehen, hatte **dies** aber, weil er sich für immer gut aufgehoben geglaubt hatte, völlig versäumt.

I understand from [this post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43539/es-waren-dies-eine-taschenbibel) that the first *dies* refers to *Gegenstände*.  I assume that the second *dies* refers to *Gelegenheit*.

**QUESITON**

1. Would it be grammatical to replace *dies* with *diese*--so that the pronoun actually matches the gender and case of the thing it refers to?
2. If no to 1 (i.e. *diese* would actually be ungrammatical), please explain why.
3. If yes to 1, is *dies* still better (e.g. in point of style)?
4. What are the general rules governing either the mandatory, preferred, or permissible use of *dies* instead of *diese* or another form of the pronoun to match the gender and number of the referent?

**BACKGROUND**

By 4, I am wondering whether *dies* could have been mandatory, preferred or permissible if the referent was e.g. *Frau*.

I don't know why 'referent' means the thing referred to.  It looks like the thing that does the referring. 'Designatum' is too grandiose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Während seines Aufenthaltes beim Onkel hätte er freilich die beste Gelegenheit gehabt, der Frage nach der Gefährlichkeit der Irländer auf den Grund zu gehen, hatte **dies** aber, weil er sich für immer gut aufgehoben geglaubt hatte, völlig versäumt.

**Dies** refers to the infinitive clause *der Frage nach der Gefährlichkeit der Irländer auf den Grund zu gehen*. A possible replacement would be **es**.

If you replaced it by *diese*, it would refer to *Gelegenheit*.

Referring to the just completed infinitive clause instead of the far away *Gelegenheit* makes the text snappier and easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense and annuls, as it were, the questions for *Gelegenheit*. Could you however consider *Gegenstände*? I.e., why not use *diese* (question 1), etc. | Also you seem to think that *dies* could have referred to *Gelegenheit* (though less snappy) if the *zu*-clause was unavailable as referent?

Comment: If there was no *zu-clause* inbetween, **dies** would refer to nothing. People reading the sentence would assume there was some object missing because the gender does not match *Gelegenheit*.